# React doesn't render sub array of the props when it hidden before

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have a screen that pass data to a screen component template. Here is the template.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { List, ListItem, Icon, Body, Right } from "native-base";
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react/native";
import styles from "./styles";

@inject("view.app", "domain.user", "app", "routerActions")
@observer
class ListDropdown extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      categoryDrop: null,
    };
  }

    categoryDropdown(id) {
        if (this.state.categoryDrop === id) {
            this.setState({ categoryDrop: null });
            return;
        }
        this.setState({ categoryDrop: id });
        console.log(this.state.categoryDrop);
    }

    render() {
    return (
      <List
        removeClippedSubviews={false}
        bounces={false}
        dataArray={this.props.datas}
        renderRow={item =>
          <View>
            <ListItem
              onPress={() =>  this.categoryDropdown(item.id)}
              style={{ marginLeft: 0, paddingLeft: 10 }}
            >
              <Body>
                <Text style={styles.listHeading}>
                  {item.value}
                </Text>
              </Body>
              <Right>
                <Icon
                  style={styles.listIconHeading}
                  name={
                    item.id === this.state.categoryDrop
                      ? "ios-arrow-up"
                      : "ios-arrow-down"
                  }
                />
              </Right>
            </ListItem>
            {this.state.categoryDrop === item.id &&
              <List
                removeClippedSubviews={false}
                bounces={false}
                dataArray={item.sublist}
                renderRow={sublistItem =>
                  <ListItem
                    icon
                    style={styles.listDropItems}
                    onPress={() =>
                      this.props.navigation.navigate("ProductList")}
                  >
                    <Body>
                      <Text style={styles.listDropText}>
                        {sublistItem.value}
                      </Text>
                    </Body>
                    <Right>
                      <Icon style={styles.listIcon} name="ios-arrow-forward" />
                    </Right>
                  </ListItem>}
              />}
          </View>}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default ListDropdown;
```

Parent screen Code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Container,
  List,
  ListItem,
  Content,
  Card,
  CardItem,
  Left,
  Right,
  Button
} from "native-base";
import MyFooter from "../../components/Footer";
import BannerSlider from "../../components/BannerSlider/index.js";
import ListDropdown from "../../components/ListDropdown";
import ThemeHeader from "../../components/Header/index.js";
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react/native";
import styles from "./styles.js";
import data from "../HomePage/data";

@inject("view.app", "domain.user", "app", "routerActions")
@observer
class Category extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      categoryDrop: null
    };
  }
  categoryDropdown(id) {

      if (this.state.categoryDrop === id) {
      this.setState({ categoryDrop: null });
      this.setState({ arrowDirection: "ios-arrow-dropdown-outline" });
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ categoryDrop: id });
  }
  render() {
    const navigation = this.props.navigation;
    var ListDropdownData = [
      {
          id: 275,
          value: "Fitness",
          sublist: [{id: 131, value: "Treadmill"}, {id: 132, value: "Crosstrainer"}, {id: 134, value: "Rowing"}, {id: 134, value: "Rowing"},  ]
      },
      {
          id: 125,
          value: "Swimming",
          sublist: [{id: 138, value: "Swimwear"}, {id: 139, value: "Goggles"}, {id: 141, value: "Swimming Accessories"} ]
      },
      {
          id: 126,
          value: "Badminton",
          sublist: [{id: 138, value: "Swimwear"}, {id: 139, value: "Goggles"}, {id: 325, value: "Badminton Apparel"} ],
      },
      {
          id: 4,
          value: "Gitar",
          sublist: [{id: 158, value: "Amplifier"}, {id: 184, value: "Gitar Elektrik"}, {id: 194, value: "Gitar Akustik"} ]
      },
    ];
    return (
      <Container>
        <ThemeHeader PageTitle="CATEGORIES" IconRight="ios-search" />
        <Content showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <Card>
            <CardItem style={{ padding: 0 }}>
              <ListDropdown navigation={navigation} datas={ListDropdownData} />
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
          <Card>
            <CardItem
              style={{ paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0 }}
            >
              <Left>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, color: "#696d79" }}>
                  RECENTLY VIEWED
                </Text>
              </Left>
              <Right>
                <Button small transparent>
                  <Text style={styles.clearAll}>CLEAR ALL</Text>
                </Button>
              </Right>
            </CardItem>
            <CardItem style={{ paddingHorizontal: 5, paddingVertical: 0 }}>
              <ScrollView
                directionalLockEnabled={false}
                horizontal={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              >
                <List
                  removeClippedSubviews={false}
                  bounces={false}
                  contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}
                  dataArray={data}
                  renderRow={item =>
                    <BannerSlider
                      imageStyle={{
                        height: 100,
                        width: 170,
                        resizeMode: "stretch"
                      }}
                      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ProductList")}
                      bannerImageText={item.bannerImageText}
                      bannerImageSource={item.bannerImageSource}
                      bannerSmallText={item.bannerSmallText}
                      navigation={navigation}
                    />}
                />
              </ScrollView>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
          <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
            <ListItem noBorder>
              <Text style={styles.contactListItem}>Contact Us</Text>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem noBorder>
              <Text style={styles.contactListItem}>FAQs</Text>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem noBorder>
              <Text style={styles.contactListItem}>About Us</Text>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem noBorder>
              <Text style={styles.contactListItem}>Terms of use</Text>
            </ListItem>
          </View>
        </Content>
        <MyFooter navigation={navigation} selected={"categories"} />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
export default Category;
```

The list itself is rendered, the problem is the sub array won't appear after the we pressed the button. I tried to remove the state categoryDrop check on the list, and the data are rendered.

also checked the function did work and the state changed. Why does the list won't dropdown when i used the props?

Comment: First of all, you need to use props for data being passed into a component like from an API. You need to read on when to use state vs props.

Comment: @Ashutosh I used state just for testing because props doesn't work. In the actual flow i will use props.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are rendering the list before the api response, so your list is already render before you have array of data and after api response your view is not render again. You can set a if condition before your list, it won't execute until you receive data from api.

```
if(this.props.arr && this.props.arr.length>0){
    <List />
}
```

Comment: i tried it. The problem is the data is there, i tried to log the data and it does exist. I try to make drop down menu here, and i pull the categories with the sub array. The problem is when i change the state i just isn't there.

Comment: which data state you are changing?

Comment: categoryDrop, it just to define which category to unhidden in the category list. The cateogy definetly there as when i tried to render the data directly it without hide and unhidden it's all there. The one that doesn't rendered is the sublist, the list itself is rendered.

Comment: Did you check when you re-render the category list, at that time you have the sublist of that category for which you want to show the sublist?
It might happen that at the initial time you will have the sublist but after some time sublist gets null and it doesnt show sublist.
To detect the state and props change use react/redux devtool, which will be easy to detect the changes of state & props